# Python urllib.quote only for given method argument fails

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

I tried to learn python and therefore program a small scraper.
I got quite far, but have a problem concatenating strings.

My plan is to add thinks only if they are given as argument to my function. Code looks like this:

```
def buildUrl(self, artist, album=None, title=None):

    url = self.url + urllib.quote(artist)

    if title is not None: url = url + '/' + urllib.quote(album)
    if album is not None: url = url + '/' + urllib.quote(title)

    return url
```

Now the problem is I get the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\lony\workspace-python\scrapper\bs.py", line 22, in buildUrl           
    if title is not None: url = url + '/' + urllib.quote(album)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1269, in quote
    raise TypeError('None object cannot be quoted')
TypeError: None object cannot be quoted
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` conditions don't match up:

```
if title is not None: url = url + '/' + urllib.quote(album)
   ^^^^^                                             ^^^^^
```

Comment: OMG it is that easy ;) THANKs!

Comment: Following up question do you know why I have to add self as first argument. If I call the function my first argument is artist and nothing related to self, why is that working?

Comment: `self` is an implied argument. It's passed to all instance methods.

Comment: Hm .. so I do always need it? What are alternatives?

Comment: `self` is just the canonical name. You could pass in `potato` and it'd work, but you always need some sort of `self` argument for every class method.